# How to hide the layout when the screen remains untouched by the user?

Tags: android

I has use OnTouchListener to visible layout1 while screen was touch.
Now I want invisible layout1 while the screen didn't be touch three seconds.
But I don't know which event listener can I use?

Now the problem has be resolved.
But another one was appear.
I use:

```
class unTouchTask extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
if(untouch == true) {
RelativeLayout rl = (
RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
timer.cancel();
untouch = false;}
}
    }
```

Below error on line`rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option1 : You need to run a timer to track the user intraction inactive time, and on every user touch you will need to reset the timer.

Code your timer as below:

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
       
       //hide your layout
   
   }

}
```

And in the event listener to start this update, the following Timer() instance is used:

```
if(startTime == 0L) {
   startTime = evt.getWhen();
   timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 300, 200);
}
```

NOTE :In particular, note the 300, 200 parameters. The first parameter means wait 300 ms before running the clock update task the first time. The second means repeat every 200ms after that, until stopped.

## Option 2: Fortunately, the role of Timer can be replaced by the android.os.Handler class, with a few tweaks

You can get more detailed example at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Timer and TimerTask to schedule something to happen in a time interval.
If the user ever touches the screen, cancel the timer and reset it. You will need to UI related stuff in the UI thread. This [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this Error because You can use threads but all the views, and all the views related APIs, must be invoked from the main thread (also called UI thread.) So the solution to this is to use the Handler. A Handler is an object that will post messages back to the UI thread for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html will guide you to code handlers.

The second option is to use *runOnUiThread*. Following is what I do in my thread :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        titleProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
//long operation here
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       titleProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```